# ATBSWP 2nd edition Chapter 12, Opening all search results for google or other websites doesn't work

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The exercise here is to make a program so that we could simply type a search term on the command line and the program would open a browser with the top several results in new tabs.

The code needs to do the following:

1. Read command line arguments from sys.argv
2. Fetch the search result page with the requests module
3. Find the link in each result
4. Call the webbrowser.open() function to open the links.

In the example, the book use the code below for https://pypi.org and it works perfectly.

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
print('Searching...')    # display text while downloading the search result page
res = requests.get('https://pypi.org/search/?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

#Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

#Open a browser tab for each result.
link_elems = soup.select('.package-snippet')

num_open = min(5, len(link_elems))
for i in range(num_open):
    url_to_open = 'https://pypi.org' + link_elems[i].get('href')
    print('Opening', url_to_open)
    webbrowser.open(url_to_open)
```

However, this does not work with Google. I'm not quite sure why but there are two major problems that I think prevents the code from working which I couldn't solve

1. The url for pypi.org when you search something is simply "pypi.org/search/?q=search+something"
   but for Google, typing "google.com/search/?q=python", for example, would return a 404 error.
2. For pypi, looking through the rest of the HTML source, it looks like the *package-snippet* class is used only for search result links. For Google, I couldn't figure out what the class is and am stuck here. I've tried several complicated patterns such as 'MUxGbd.v0nnCb' that I found to recur on the browser's developers tool to no avail.

The book does mention that Google employs measures that make scraping their search results difficult. Perhaps a completely different method is required?

Edit: ThaooBlues' answer solves the first issue but I still couldn't figure out what argument to put for soup.select()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional so my answer may be not really clear but you should remove the last "/" of your url like :

"google.com/search?q=python"

"pypi.org/search?q=search+something"

This should work properly.

For the google search results it may be easier to use an existing module like [this](https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/) that do exactly the work you want. If you really want to do it yourself, you should consider following this tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-google-search-results-using-python-beautifulsoup/) and adapting it a bit to get the URL you want.

Answer (score 0):

For the google url that you're concatenating the search terms to, try this:

```
"https://www.google.com/search?q="
```

`"https://www.google.com/search?q=python"` does give me the correct search result on Google.